# D3.js is not recognized by PyCharm

Tags: python, html, d3.js, pycharm

1. I have installed the D3.js library from the Javascript tab in Settings
2. Also imported the src using  `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`
3. Here is my app.py:

   ```
   @app.route('/')
   def my_form():
       return render_template('circle.html')
   ```
4. Here is circle.html

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <script>
   var canvas = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width",500)
     .attr("width",300);

   var circle = canvas.append("circle")
                      .attr("cx", 250)
                      .attr("cy", 250)
                      .attr("r", 50)
                      .attr("fill","red");

   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Where did you import the d3js in your code? (means point 2)

Comment: Apologies for that; I missed that out while pasting the question. I've added it in now.
But the output is still the same. I just get a blank screen when I render circle.html

Comment: Try to add it in the body, not in the head tag

Comment: Doesn't work? Still the same.
I included the src as an attribute of the <script> tag within body and removed the script inside head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, I suppose, a typo in your Javascript code:

```
var canvas = d3.select("body")
               .append("svg")
               .attr("width",500)
               .attr("width",300);
```

As you can see, you didn't set the *height* property; instead you set twice the width property.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25d3qr5g/1/) for the complete code.

Comment: Thank you giordano. My bad; can't believe I missed that out. Should stop copy pasting code snippets.

Comment: No problem, glad to help you.